# Autowired doesn't create repository value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, spring-data

I have the following classes

Sample.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE")

public class Sample extends Model {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;
    }
}
```

SampleRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Sample, Long> {

    List<Sample> findByName(String name);
}
```

Application.java(Main class)

```
public class Application {

@Autowired
SampleRepository repository;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Application().doThings();
}

public void doThings() {
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.setName("arun");
    repository.save(sample);
}

}
```

I don't have a sprint-context.xml

When I try to run the main class(Application.java), the repository object is always null.

How should I configure this to populate value in repository object by autowiring?

Or why is the repository object value always null?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get your app working would be to use Spring Boot. Here's an example of a command line application: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-simple

So your app would look something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    SampleRepository repository;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        this.repository.doThings();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.setApplicationContextClass(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.class);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void doThings() {
        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setName("arun");
        repository.save(sample);
    }
}
```

Comment: The latest version is 1.2.5. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot

Answer (score -1):

Because you're not in a Java EE environment (you have a main method) and because you're not initializing Spring in your code. Depending on where you want to go, look up the appropriate documentation.

Comment: not related to java-ee, spring DI is a lightweight container